# std::string Not Getting Terminated Properly

Tags: c++, string, std, outputstream, fileoutputstream

When I send a `std::string` to the output stream by calling `ostream << string.c_str();` the string is not being terminated correctly. Why is this?

```
class Application {
public:
    bool print() {
        out << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
        std::ifstream inFileStream;
        inFileStream.open("./test.html");
        if(!inFileStream.is_open()) {
            out << "Error Opening File";
            return true;
        }
        boost::uintmax_t templateSize = boost::filesystem::file_size("./test.html");
        std::string output;
        char* templateData = new char[templateSize];
        char* bytePtr = templateData;
        inFileStream.read(templateData, templateSize);

        std::ofstream logFile;
        logFile.open("/tmp/test.log");
        while(*bytePtr != EOF) {
            if(*bytePtr ==  '{')
                readVar(&bytePtr, &output);
            else
                output.push_back(*bytePtr);

            bytePtr++;
        }
        delete[] templateData;
        output.push_back(0);
        logFile << output.c_str();
        return true;

    }
private:
    void readVar(char** bytePtrPtr, std::string* output) {
        while(**bytePtrPtr != EOF) {
            if(**bytePtrPtr == '}')
                return;
            output->push_back('*');
            (*bytePtrPtr)++;
        }
    }
};
```

The output of this *(inside the log file)* includes the properly parsed `test.html`, but also some additional byte garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The read data isn't terminated by `EOF`. You dump some junk from the file which sits between the end of the file and the first `char` which converts to `EOF`. You should stop your loop adding characters to `output` once you processed `n` chars where `n` is the result of the call to `inFileStream.read(...)`.

Comment: Additionally, it hasn't been required to call `.c_str()` to an output stream for quite a while.  `logFile << output;` works fine.